# Load score of specific user

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am trying to introduce gaming services in Android. Is there a way  I can load the score of the current user? I need the previous score so I can add to it

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it though the game services, you have to retrieve all the scores of a leaderboard (selecting time scope and social/public) and then find your user.

the best way to do that is using [GamesClient.loadPlayerCenteredScores](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadPlayerCenteredScores%28com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.OnLeaderboardScoresLoadedListener,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) with the `maxResults` argument to 1. This should return a JSONArray containing only the user.

However, I suggest you to store the data on local storage and only retrieving the Game services values as a support.